# reason: '-[_UIFullscreenPresentationController adaptivePresentationController]:

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have added search bar to my tableview.But when i search some thing in my table view and if i press cancel default button for search bar to dismiss my keyboard means my app getting crash.

Crash report :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIFullscreenPresentationController adaptivePresentationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff10a88cd80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b18ed85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ca8adeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b197d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0ddcfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0dd8a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010dfda4c2 -[UISearchController _searchPresentationController] + 134
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010db8ad77 -[_UISearchControllerTransplantSearchBarAnimator animateTransition:] + 215
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d6f148f __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 2638
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d58ef62 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d5a2e4c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d5af147 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0b3c37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0b3ba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0a97fb __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b0a90f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ff92ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d582f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    17  Screen 6                            0x000000010a791e82 main + 114
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f1c892d start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


       let searchConroller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)



    @IBOutlet var TableViewList: UITableView!

       // array to store the value from json
    var arrDict = [Businessdata]()
     var filteredData = [Businessdata]()
    var marrFilteredCountryList = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
          searchConroller.searchBar.hidden = true





     searchConroller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchConroller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true


    }



    func filterContentForSearch(searchText: String, scope: String = "All")
    {

        filteredData = arrDict.filter { Businessdata in
            return Businessdata.BusinessName!.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
        }
        TableViewList.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        self.LocationLabel.text = "in Toronto, ON"
        self.TypeLabel.text = BTdata?.BTNames
        self.BTypeId = BTdata?.BTIds
        LoadBusinesses()
    }



    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    }


    @IBAction func searchPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {
//        



        if searchConroller.searchBar.hidden
        {
             searchConroller.searchBar.hidden = false
            TableViewList.tableHeaderView = searchConroller.searchBar
             //yConstraint.constant = 44;
        }
        else
        {
            searchConroller.searchBar.hidden = true
            //-searchBar.bounds.height
              yConstraint.constant = 0;

        }

    }


    // web services method
    func LoadBusinesses()
    {
        self.arrDict.removeAll()

        let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("access_token") as! String

        let headers = ["x-access-token": token]

        var StringUrl:String = "http://some url”

        StringUrl += "?lat=\(self.NewCurrentLatitude)"

        StringUrl += "&long=\(self.NewCurrentLongitude)"

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: StringUrl)!,
                                          cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error)
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? NSDictionary
                {
                    let success = json["success"] as? Int

                    if (success == 1)
                    {
                        if let reposArray = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary]
                        {
                                for item in reposArray
                                {
                                    let itemObj = item as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

                                    let b_type = itemObj!["business_type"]

                                    // taxis type
                                    if (b_type as? String == self.BTypeId)
                                    {
                                        self.arrDict.append(Businessdata(json:item))
                                        self.TableViewList.reloadData()
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let message = json["message"] as? String
                        print(message)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Json Data error")
                }
                })
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        //
        var numOfSection: NSInteger = 0

        if arrDict.count > 0
        {
            self.TableViewList.backgroundView = nil
            numOfSection = 1
        }
        else
        {
            let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.TableViewList.bounds.size.width, self.TableViewList.bounds.size.height))
            noDataLabel.text = "No Data Available"
            noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 106.0/255.0, blue: 176.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            noDataLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            self.TableViewList.backgroundView = noDataLabel
        }
        return numOfSection
    }


    // number of rows
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        ResultCount.text = String(self.arrDict.count)+" Results"

//        if searchConroller.active && searchConroller.searchBar.text = "" {
//            
//            return filteredData.count
//        }

        if searchConroller.active && searchConroller.searchBar.text! != "" {

             return filteredData.count
        }
        else
        {
       return self.arrDict.count
        }
    }

    // header view
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
    {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return headerView
    }

    // calling each cell based on tap and users ( premium / non premium )
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        if((arrDict[indexPath.row].FeaturedBusiness) != nil)
        {
            let cell1:premiumUsercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3") as! premiumUsercell

            cell1.phoneNumber = arrDict[indexPath.section].ContactNumber!
            cell1.vendorName3.text = arrDict[indexPath.section].BusinessName
            cell1.vendorAdddress3.text = arrDict[indexPath.section].Address
            cell1.VendorRating3.rating = arrDict[indexPath.section].Rating!

            cell1.latlng = arrDict[indexPath.section].BusinessLatLng!

            latlng = arrDict[indexPath.section].BusinessLatLng!


            let FeaturedValues = arrDict[indexPath.row].FeaturedBusiness

            cell1.FeaturedDisplayText.text = FeaturedValues!.valueForKey("display_text") as? String

            let BImage = arrDict[indexPath.section].StoreImages

            let BMainImage = BImage![0] as! NSDictionary

            let FinalImage = BMainImage.valueForKey("url") as! String

            if let imgURL2 = NSURL(string: FinalImage)
            {
                let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL2)

                let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

                let Imgtask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
                {
                    (data, response, error) -> Void in

                    if (error == nil && data != nil)
                    {
                        func display_image()
                        {
                            cell1.vendorImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        }
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
                    }
                }
                Imgtask.resume()
            }
            cell1.getDirectionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ContainerViewController.GetDirection), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

            return cell1
        }




        if searchConroller.active && searchConroller.searchBar.text! != "" {



            let cell:customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell

            cell.vendorName.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].BusinessName
            cell.vendorAddress.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].Address
            cell.VendorRating.rating = filteredData[indexPath.row].Rating!
            return cell
        }
        else

        {
            let cell:customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell

            cell.vendorName.text = arrDict[indexPath.row].BusinessName
            cell.vendorAddress.text = arrDict[indexPath.row].Address
            cell.VendorRating.rating = arrDict[indexPath.row].Rating!
            return cell
        }
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc: BusinessDetailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BusinessDetailViewController") as! BusinessDetailViewController

        if searchConroller.active && searchConroller.searchBar.text! != "" {
            vc.BusinessData = filteredData[indexPath.row]

        }
        else {
            vc.BusinessData = arrDict[indexPath.row]

        }


      self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }



}

extension ContainerViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearch(searchConroller.searchBar.text!)
    }

}
```

This is my first project , please help me out.How to solve.

Thanks

Comment: add exception break point and see in which line it is crashing

Comment: Can you post the minimum code just enough to cause a crash.

Answer (score 7):

This can happen if the button being tapped attempts to modally present a new view controller.  Since a UISearchController is already being presented, this can cause unexpected behavior or raise an exception.

If there is any code in your button action that is triggering a segue, try changing the type of segue to Show.  If you're using interface builder, this would be the Kind property in the attributes inspector.

Answer (score 4):

you can try set definesPresentationContext to true in ContainerViewController

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func presentOtherViewController() {
    if let presented = presentedViewController {
        presented.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.present(otherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        present(otherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```